# Reverse proxy nginx not working; does anyone know why?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, pfsense

For this project at school we got 1 public IP address on which we want to run multiple webservices (Roundcube webmail, nextcloud and webconfigurator for the firewall). On the public IP itself we have a pfSense firewall running, which also takes care of the routing. In the LAN of the firewall we have 3 servers, a mailserver (with webmail), a Nextcloud server and a nginx server which I'm trying to get working as a reverse proxy. First I tried to be able to access the webconfigurator, but it doesn't work and I can't find out why. Here is the configuration:

```
server {
  server_name pfsense.domain.com;

  location ~ {
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_pass http://10.1.1.2:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect on;
  }
}
```

The pfSense is on the local IP 10.1.1.2. I forwarded port 80 and 443 to the nginx server, but the configuration doesn't work. The filename is `/etc/nginx/sites-available/webservers.conf` and I created a symlink in the `sites-enabled` folder. I copied the configuration from another thread on this Stack Exchange.

Comment: `location ~` is not correct. I can't tell you what your config should be as it will depend on the urls you want to use. If you just want to catch everything try  `location /`

Comment: Alright, so now it is just catching everything and redirecting it? I want to use this rule for this specific domain only, there should be other 'rules' for different domains, like mail.domain.com should redirect to 10.1.1.4 for example

Comment: In that case you would add an additional server block with the required `server_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself, by just going step by step. I started with this:

```
   server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.x.x.2;
        }
    }
```

And then I added extra options step by step. I found the options and their descriptions on http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html. I finally ended up with the following, which works fine!

```
}
server {
    server_name mail.domain.eu www.mail.domain.eu;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.1.1.4;
        proxy_set_header Host       $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Host       $host;
    }
```